# How to create a list that represent the number of times a given item was shown?

Tags: python, data-structures

This problem seems really stupid bu I can't get my head around it.

I have the following list:

```
a = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
```

I have to produce a second list which have the same size as the previous one but the values that appear should be the amount of times that a value showed up in the array until that point. For example:

```
b = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

So b[0] = 1 because it's the first time the item '2' appear on the 'a' list. b[5] = 2 and b[7] = 3 because it's the second and third time that the item '2' appear on the list 'a'.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
b = []
d = defaultdict(int)

for x in a:
  d[x] +=1
  b.append(d[x])

print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Comment: In one line with counter and a bit of misuse of the if in a list comprehension: 
`counter = Counter(); [counter[val] for val in a if not counter.update([val])]`

Answer (score 0):

I think using dictionary might help you, basically I am iterating the list and storing the current frequency of the number.

```
a = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3]
d = {}
z = []
for i in a:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = 1
        z.append(1)
    else:
        d[i]+=1
        z.append(d[i])
print(z)
output = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```